# How to update PageBook control in SWT

Tags: swt, refresh, jface

I am currently using the PageBook control to display different pages depending on the user's action.

[image]

Here is a brief source of WizardPage above:

```
override createControl(Composite parent) {
        var composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE) as Composite;
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout())
        createSelectDomainFileGroup(composite);
        createDomainGroup(composite);
        pageBook(composite)
        setControl(composite)
    }
```

I added pageBook(composite) in this method because I think that the first method to be called when the class is called, createControl() should specify all areas initially.

Here's how I want it to work.

1. Check the'Use Domain Custom' CheckBox.
2. Then the'Choose File' Button is activated.
3. Click the'Choose File' button and select the extension of the Excel (.xls, .xlsx) file.
4. Check whether the selected file is damaged through internal logic.
5. If it is a normal file, update the desired value in PageBook.

And pageBook was displayed under the following conditions.

```
if (isValidExcelFile()) {
    Display.^default.asyncExec([
        setMessage(MessageFormat.format(Messages.ChooseDomainFileWizardPage_9, domainFileName));
        domainFileNameText.setText(domainFileName);
        setPageComplete(true);
        workbook = this.workbook
        pagebook.showPage(sheetPage)
    ])
    this.option.setExcelFile(true);
}
```

<< Modified >>
sheetPage is created as below.

```
def pageBook(Composite parent) {
        var container = parent as Composite

        container.Composite [
            new Composite(parent, SWT.NORMAL) => [
                layoutData = FILL_HORIZONTAL[]
                layout = GridLayout
                pagebook = PageBook[
                    layout = GridLayout
                    layoutData = FILL_HORIZONTAL[]
                ]
            ]
        ]

        // sheetPage
        sheetPage = pagebook.Composite [
            layout = GridLayout[
                numColumns = 2
                marginWidth = 0
                marginHeight = 0
                makeColumnsEqualWidth = false
            ]

            layoutData = FILL_HORIZONTAL


            new Label(it, SWT.NORMAL) => [
                text = Messages.ChooseDomainFileWizardPage_12
            ]
           ..... more source
```

<< Modified >>
The Pagebook is called as follows:

```
if (domainFileName.nullOrEmpty) {
            return;
        } else if (domainFileName.toLowerCase.endsWith(".xls") || domainFileName.toLowerCase.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            this.option.filename = domainFileName;

            if (isValidExcelFile()) {
                Display.^default.asyncExec([
                    setMessage(MessageFormat.format(Messages.ChooseDomainFileWizardPage_9, domainFileName));
                    domainFileNameText.setText(domainFileName);
                    setPageComplete(true);
                    workbook = this.workbook
                    pagebook.showPage(sheetPage)
                ])

                this.option.setExcelFile(true);
        .... more source
```

However, the desired value is not displayed properly.
In my opinion, since I did pageBook(Composite) on the first createControl().. I think the control in the pageBook area is displayed, but the value is not updated.

I want to know how to refresh the screen of the pageBook control that has already been loaded.

Comment: What programming language is this? The Display.asyncExec is not needed (it is hardly ever needed). How is sheetPage created? It must have the page book as its parent. How is the PageBook created? You need to show us something closer to a [mre]

Comment: @greg--449 1) This Language is Xtend. 2)I think the reason to use Display.async is to use UI thread and logic processing process separately. 3) We edited the post where the sheetPage was created. Please check again. PageBook was implemented in createControl(), and this was also modified. please check.